# Using second router to cover dead wifi spots

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking

I have a verizon fios router being used as my main device. I would like to (wirelessly) connect a motorola surfboard SBG6580 to the fios router, and use the motorola router to cover some spotty areas where the fios router's signal is not good. I hope that makes sense. How can I do this? Obviously specific steps would be preferred, but I realize that may be impossible considering I have two very specific devices. So if someone can give me some general steps that would be useful. Btw, anyone in my house should be able to connect to BOTH routers - the fios one and the motorola one - even though the fios one is actually connected to the internet, and the motorola one's connection will just be passed through the fios one. I hope that makes sense. I am a software developer and I am somewhat familiar with networking but I am out of my element here. Thanks.

Comment: Your question regarding a home network is off-topic here but would be perfect for Super User. I've recommended that it be moved so it won't be necessary to ask again over there. Refer to the [faq] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work. The SBG6580 is a cable router so you don't have the same options you would have with a different gateway/router and, as far as I know, it cannot be configured as a repeater.

Comment: So why can't I set it up as if it is a separate network (different IP range, SSID, etc) and connect it to the first fios one? Basically configure it as if it was it's own network with the fios router being it's "first hop" to getting out to the internet.

Comment: That is why I brought up my comment about it being a cable router and not standard gateway. Also, how do you mean "connect it to the first one"? I thought you wanted all wireless? If you are going to wire them together you have more options.

Comment: Yes I do want all wireless. I don't see why I cannot set it up as a subnetwork, tell it to connect to the fios router on its WAN, and then be a happy camper. I guess you're saying that isn't possible with my router but it seems to me that what I'm trying to do is pretty standard for all routers..?

Comment: It is not standard for a wireless router to be able to connect to two source and route traffic between them all on the wireless side.

Comment: So my router cannot.. route? So I cannot 1) set up two separate subnets and connect them wirelessly OR 2) set them up as part of the same network and connect them wirelessly .. so what CAN I do with this thing? Anyhway, I'm very stubborn but you've convinced me to give up. I guess I'll buy a wireless repeater.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make one big wi-fi network using 2 or more wi-fi access points (AP), they should have same SSID and same encryption parameters. Second access point should work in bridge mode, and be connected to same local network as another one.

In your case (you don't want the wire between router and second access point) - second AP must support Wireless Repeater mode, but not every access point can work as repeater.

Comment: So why can't I set it up as if it is a separate network (different IP range, SSID, etc) and connect it to the first fios one? Basically configure it as if it was it's own network with the fios router being it's "first hop" to getting out to the internet. Btw this router is only 1 year old, and was advertised as having multiple capabilities, I think it is a little better than you're giving credit for.

Comment: In other words, I would be fine with the motorola router being on a separate subnet, and then being connected to the fios one.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your second router as a separate network as follows

1. Make sure the second wireless network has a different subnet applied.
2. To the WAN port, supply an IP address within subnet of your fios router
3. Set up a static default route on that points to your fios router